# Iwasawa Decomposition

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, functional-analysis

I was asked to prove that if

$$ T_{n}^{+}(\mathbb{R}) \subseteq M_{n}(\mathbb{R})$$

denotes the set of upper triangular matrices with positive diagonal entries, then prove that the multiplication map

$$ \mu : O_{n}(\mathbb{R}) \times T_{n}^{+}(\mathbb{R}) \rightarrow GL_{n}(\mathbb{R})$$

is a homeomorphism where $O_{n}(\mathbb{R})$ is the set of orthogonal matrices.

Using polar decomposition, I could write

$$ GL_{n}(\mathbb{R}) = O_{n}(\mathbb{R}) \times Pd_{n}(\mathbb{R})$$

the positive definite matrices. Then positive definite matrices are unitarily diagonalizable, but that does not seem to take me towards $T_{n}^{+}(\mathbb{R})$.

Any ideas about the above?

Comment: Did you try to read any books on Lie theory? Iwasawa decomposition will be covered in the most. You can also prove it by induction on $n$. A good idea might be to draw an ellipse and find a shearing transformation converting it to the ellipse whose axes are parallel to coordinate lines.

Comment: To establish the bijection, consider an element of $GL_n$ as an ordered basis and try to make it orthonormal via the action of an element of $T_n^+$. There is an induction algorithm for this that you've probably seen before...

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis Could you be a little more explicit?

Comment: @Vishal: The Gram-Schmidt algorithm is what you're looking for - the $j$th vector in the produced orthonormal frame is expressed as a linear combination of the first $j$ vectors in the initial frame, making the transition matrix triangular.